# Vue js: set notification count to zero

Tags: vue.js

in my Vue Js code below, i created count for notification socket, so whenever a new notification received it count+ and appears beside the icon ... now i wanted to set back the count to zero when a user click on notification icon but i couldn't figure out how to do it.
below in app.vue i set a prop called `number` and i pass it to the sidebar to appear on all project pages , this number is the count of the notifications .. is there a way to set it back to zero after user click on the icon in the side bar?

```js
<template>
  
<router-view :number="count" @send="getNewCount">

<sidebar :number="count" />

</router-view>
</template>

<script>
import sidebar from "@/views/Layout/DashboardLayout.vue";
import axios from "axios";
import {
    io
} from "socket.io-client";

let socket = io("h***********/");
export default {
components: {
    sidebar,


  },
    data() {
        return {
            user2: JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user")),
            count: 0,
            today: null,
            
        };
        
    },
       props: {
    number: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },},
    async created() {
        console.log(this.count);
        const response = await axios.get(
            `https://l*********rs/api/${this.user2._id}/`, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("user"),
                },
            }
        );

        // await this.$store.dispatch("user", response.data.response);

        socket.emit("user_connected", this.user2.username);
        // console.log(this.user2,"userr")
        socket.on("verify_connection", (data) => {
            this.verify_connection = data;
            console.log(data, "s")
        });

        socket.emit("user_connected", this.user2.username);
        socket.on("verify_connection", (data) => {
            console.log("heyy", data);
            this.verify_connection = data;
        });
        socket.on("updated_flat", (data) => {

            console.log("heyy", data);
            this.makeToast(" success ", "'b-toaster-top-center");

     

        });
        socket.on("test", (data) => {

            console.log("heyy", data);
            // this.makeToast("success", "b-toaster-top-right");

          

        });

        ;
    },

    methods: {

        //   playSound() {
        //   var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
        //   audio.play();
        // },

        getNewCount(data) {
            this.count = data;
        },
        makeToast(variant = null, toaster, append = false) {
            this.$bvToast.toast(" edited ", {
                title: "BootstrapVue Toast",
                variant: variant,
                autoHideDelay: 10000,
                toaster: toaster,
                position: "top-right",

                appendToast: append,
            });
            // this.playSound();
            this.count = this.count + 1;
                console.log(this.count,"count");
        },

    }
}
</script>
```

sidebar:

```js
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
  
    <side-bar  >
      <template slot="links">
      
       <sidebar-item v-if="roles ==='Admin'"
 
                  :link="{ 
                    name: ' notifications',
                    path: '/notifications',
                    icon: 'ni ni-bell-55 text-green'
                  }">  
               
        </sidebar-item>
<p class="notifCount" v-if="roles ==='Admin'">  {{ number }}  </p>


        
      </template>

      
    </side-bar>
    <div class="main-content">
      <dashboard-navbar :type="$route.meta.navbarType"></dashboard-navbar>

      <div @click="$sidebar.displaySidebar(false)">
        <fade-transition :duration="200" origin="center top" mode="out-in">
          <!-- your content here -->
          <router-view></router-view>
        </fade-transition>
      </div>
      <content-footer v-if="!$route.meta.hideFooter"></content-footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  /* eslint-disable no-new */
  import PerfectScrollbar from 'perfect-scrollbar';
  import 'perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css';

  function hasElement(className) {
    return document.getElementsByClassName(className).length > 0;
  }

  function initScrollbar(className) {
    if (hasElement(className)) {
      new PerfectScrollbar(`.${className}`);
    } else {
      // try to init it later in case this component is loaded async
      setTimeout(() => {
        initScrollbar(className);
      }, 100);
    }
  }

  import DashboardNavbar from './DashboardNavbar.vue';
  import ContentFooter from './ContentFooter.vue';
  import DashboardContent from './Content.vue';
  import { FadeTransition } from 'vue2-transitions';

  export default {
    

    components: {
      DashboardNavbar,
      ContentFooter,
      DashboardContent,
      FadeTransition
    },
     props: {
    number: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
    methods: {
      initScrollbar() {
        let isWindows = navigator.platform.startsWith('Win');
        if (isWindows) {
          initScrollbar('sidenav');
        }
      },


  },
    
    computed: {
        roles() {
            let roles = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user')).role;
            return roles;
        },},
    mounted() {
      this.initScrollbar()
  
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: There's a lot of irrelevant code in the question (e.g., routes, sockets, transitions) that makes it difficult to assess the problem. Also, the `sidebar` component you posted itself contains a `<sidebar>`, which does not seem correct. I assume `sidebar-item` contains the notification icon the user clicks to clear the notification count. Can you show the code for `sidebar-item`?

Answer (score 0):

Emit an event from `sidebar` and handle the event in the main app.

main app:

```html
<template>
  <!-- ... -->
  <sidebar :number="count" @reset="onReset" />
  <!-- ... -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    onReset() {
      // api calls, etc.
      this.count = 0;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

sidebar:

```html
<template>
  <!-- ... -->
  <button @click="$emit('reset')">Reset notification count</button>
  <!-- ... -->
</template>
```

Comment: i tried your answer but didn't work :(

Comment: "It didn't work" is very vague. What is not working? Do you get any errors in the console? Does everything render properly otherwise? Emitting events from child to parent in Vue is a fundamental way to communicate between components.

Comment: i meant it didn't change anything and it didn't reset it to zero + no console errors

Comment: @sara97 add console.log in onReset method, and check if that is getting logged.

Comment: it didn't, nothing in the console